# Reloading Table View After Watching a Rewarded Video

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata, admob-rewardedvideoad

Recently I've implemented the rewarded video feature in the code and it works well. Simply, when the user chooses the level from the table view and watches the rewarded video, it unlocks the level. But when the user closes the ad view, table view stays the same, not reloaded with the new information.

I tried some solution I found here but nothing worked.

Comment: By the way, forgot to mention, the unlocking process works well. means if I open another view controller and get back to the table view, the cells are updated with the new info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set event notification on the reward video opening controller. Use these lines of code in `viewDidLoad`

```
GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

> GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate notifies you of rewarded video lifecycle events. You are required to set the delegate prior to loading an ad. The most important event in this delegate is rewardBasedVideoAd:didRewardUserWithReward:, which is called when the user should be rewarded for watching a video. You may optionally implement other methods in this delegate.

Then you need to implement this delegate

```
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    print("Reward received with currency: \(reward.type), amount \(reward.amount).")

 // RELOAD YOUR TABLE VIEW DATA HERE
}
```

For details you can see detail implementation [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-video)

Comment: It works. Thanks Shamim for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to reload the table view manually using `tableView.reloadData()`. Either do this in viewWillAppear or in any notifications/callbacks that you trigger when the ad has finished playing.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it using NSNotification to call your tableView.reloadData():
add

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reload), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
```

to ur tableView Controller's (TVC) ViewDidLoad
and this function to ur TVC

```
@objc func reload()
{
      //setup ur new data
      self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

then just add

```
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
```

befor ur `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` in ur RewardedVideo Player